# Possibly syntax errors?

Tags: syntax

trying to graph, however graph is blank when i enter it. Please help!

```
Plot[ArcCos[1/2 (3094 + 2 x^3 Cos[25] + x (686 Cos[25] - 422 Sin[25]) + 
x^2 (27 + 15 Cos[50] - 35 Sin[50]))], {x, 0, 20}]
```

Comment: Because the value is imaginary. Try something like `Plot[Im[(*your expression*), {x, 0, 20}]`

Comment: Forgot Degree: Sin[25*Degree]?

Comment: Please see specifically: [(88571)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88571/121)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (as proposed by @xzczd),

```
equ = ArcCos[1/2 (3094 + 2 x^3 Cos[25] + x (686 Cos[25] - 422 Sin[25]) + 
x^2 (27 + 15 Cos[50] - 35 Sin[50]))]

Plot[{Re@equ, Im@equ}, {x, -20, 20}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

And check the following ressources:

[Basic Plotting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BasicPlotting.html)

[How to | Create Plots](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreatePlots.html), the **Tutorials** are quite informative

["How tos"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/HowToTopics.html)